# Dafny modification clauses and nullable fields

Tags: heap-memory, dafny

There are a lot of gotcha's with the frame system. Trying to verify another leetcode problem, essentially that the tree left and right nodes are swapped in place. Attempting to solve it as both an object method and a standalone function.

The problem with the standalone function it complains that the recursive call might violate the context's modify clause. I added everything I could think of to the modify clause but it still doesn't work. I feel like the induction should be sufficient.

```
/**
 * https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/description/
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * class TreeNode {
 *     val: number
 *     left: TreeNode | null
 *     right: TreeNode | null
 *     constructor(val?: number, left?: TreeNode | null, right?: TreeNode | null) {
 *         this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *         this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
 *         this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
 *     }
 * }

function invertTree(root: TreeNode | null): TreeNode | null {
    if(root == null) return null;
    let leftChild = invertTree(root.left);
    let rightChild = invertTree(root.right);
    root.right = leftChild;
    root.left = rightChild;
    return root;
};
 */

class TreeNode {
    var val: int;
    var left: TreeNode?;
    var right: TreeNode?;
    ghost var repr: set<TreeNode>;

    constructor(val: int, left: TreeNode?, right: TreeNode?)
        requires left != null ==> left.Valid()
        requires right != null ==> right.Valid()
        requires left != null && right != null ==> left.repr !! right.repr
        ensures this.val == val
        ensures this.left == left
        ensures this.right == right
        ensures left != null ==> this !in left.repr
        ensures right != null ==> this !in right.repr
        ensures Valid()
    {
        this.val := val;
        this.left := left;
        this.right := right;
        var leftRepr := if left != null then {left}+left.repr else {};
        var rightRepr := if right != null then {right}+right.repr else {};
        this.repr := {this} + leftRepr + rightRepr;
    }

    predicate Valid()
        reads this, repr
        decreases repr
    {
        this in repr &&
        (this.left != null ==>
        (this.left in repr
        && this !in this.left.repr
        && this.left.repr < repr
        && this.left.Valid()
        ))
        && (this.right != null ==>
        (this.right in repr
        && this !in this.right.repr
        && this.right.repr < repr
        && this.right.Valid())) &&
        (this.left != null && this.right != null ==> this.left.repr !! this.right.repr)
    }

}

method  invertBinaryTree(root: TreeNode?) returns (newRoot: TreeNode?)
    modifies {root} + (if root != null && root.left != null then {root.left} else {}) + (if root != null && root.right != null then {root.right} else {})
    requires root != null ==> root.Valid()
    ensures root != null ==> newRoot == root && newRoot.right == old(root.left) && root.left == old(root.right)
    ensures root == null ==> newRoot == null
    ensures root != null ==> newRoot != null && newRoot.repr == root.repr && newRoot.Valid()
    decreases if root == null then {} else root.repr
{
    if root != null {
        assert root in root.repr;
        assert root.Valid();
        var leftChild := null;
        if root.left != null {
            assert root.left != null;
            assert root.left.repr < root.repr;
            assert root.left.Valid();
            leftChild := invertBinaryTree(root.left);
        }
        var rightChild := root.right;
        if root.right != null  {
            assert root.right.Valid();
            rightChild := invertBinaryTree(root.right);
        }

        root.right := leftChild;
        root.left := rightChild;
        return root;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modifies clause does not take into account that the method is recursive. So you need to say not only what you modify at the top level of the recursion, but also what all possible recursive calls will modify.

I believe something like

```
modifies if root != null then root.repr else {}
```

should work for you.

Comment: That did seem to work. However, it seems I still need to prove that the child trees are still subsets than the of the root tree. Even though the repr set of the child tree is the same after the recursive method call, it no longer can prove that it is a subset of the root.repr. I assume because root.repr has changed... How would I assert/make this calculation?

Comment: In your `ensures` clause, `newRoot.repr == root.repr` should be `newRoot.repr == old(root.repr)`.

Comment: solved! https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/leetcode/invertBinaryTree.dfy Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are one of N people on the planet who are competent with the framing system. N is very small.

Comment: Haha, thanks but I still barely feel like I understand the framing system. I was honestly thought about asking you for more details about it. I have barely scratched the surface. I know about how labels and old work, but I don't know or when to apply unchanged, or fresh, or allocated.

Comment: Likewise Two-state functions and lemmas are still pretty mysterious to me.